# What's the meaning of Dustin nickname in season 3?

Tags: character, stranger-things

At the end of Stranger Things' season 3, we saw that Dustin has a new nickname: **Dusty-bun**. Also, we saw that

> he calls his girlfriend as **Suzie-poo**

As I'm not a native English speaker, I can't understand those nicknames as a fluffy thing. For me, "bun" means a part of the human body that produces "poo", where both things are related with the toilet.

As the nicknames are meant to be cute, what are the other possible translations for this context that are not given by Google Translator?

Comment: Sound like a cute couple nicknames, I know couples who call each other aholes.

Comment: Where do you get that `"bun" means a part of the human body that produces "poo"`? This is simply not true.

Comment: @BCdotWEB I found this definition at Urban Dictionary (bun = gluteus). And Google Translation says, for my language, it's a kind of hair knot commonly used by women, which is not used by Dustin.

Comment: @BCdotWEB `But how you gonna name yourself after a damn gun and have a man bun` *EMINEM-KILLSHOT*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[According to Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-poo), "poo" is:

> Added to nouns, especially personal names, ending in -y or -ie to form affectionate, playful diminutives.

---

"Bun" is not a "dirty word", and [possibly refers to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bun):

> a small, sometimes sweet, bread-based item.

Comment: Thank you. Now searching for "bun bread" I can associate bun with something cute as a sweet food. But poo remains strange for me. I understand that it is used as a suffix to be "playful", but why playful? Bunny would be a "playful" word because I would associate a person to a cute animal, but what association poo has to do with a cute thing? Maybe my question would be more fitting to english.stackexchange

Comment: bun can also be short for bunny, which is another name for a rabbit, which a lot of people consider as cute

Comment: It's worth noting that "bun" _can_ relate to the butt. Although it's often referred to as someones "buns" with the plural form being important.

Answer (score 4):

**Suzie Q** is a [very well known rock song](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Susie_Q_(song)), and Suzie Poo is likely a play on that - additionally, poo is not an unknown "pet name" addition as @BCdotWEB has [pointed out](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/101995/73830).

**Dusty Bin** was a [1980s gameshow icon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-2-1#Dusty_Bin), but as "he" was only famous in the UK, I'm guessing this is too obscure an 80s reference for the Stranger Things writers. The name is a play on "dustbin" (the UK equivalent of trashcan).